# Make Windows boot faster on SSHD

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad with a SSDH consisting of 500GB  + 8GB. When I first installed Windows 8.1 the boot time was about 10 seconds. Now, after a two months of using it, the boot time increased to 20s. I think the reason is that the OS don't boot from the 8GB cache. Is there any way to tell the SSDH what files to put in cache or how can I decrease the boot time?

Comment: You think isn't good enough to help.  Have you use the built-in tools within Windows to determine whats causing the slow boot times?

Comment: How can I use Windows built-in tools to determine whats cousing slow boot times? I've already turned off the unnecessary startup programs and some services from Task Manager.

Comment: provide a boot trace, so that I can see why the boot is longer: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Comment: What .etl file should I upload? I have 3 of them with the same name and different sizes 88 MB, 121 MB, and 430 MB.